# In App Purchase using ionic 3 and cordova getting error "the item you requested is not available for purchase"

Tags: angular, cordova, ionic-framework, in-app-purchase

I am building the app in IONIC 3 and Angular 4

I have used below ionic plugin for in app purchase:-

https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/in-app-purchase/

After installing the plugin I have added 
`"play_store_key"` in the `manifest.json` file in the `www` folder

For fetching the products from the google play

```
this.iap
.getProducts(['prod1', 'prod2','prod3','prod4'])
.then((products) => {
  console.log(products);
//  [{ productId: 'com.yourapp.prod1', 'title': '...', description: '...', 
price: '...' }, ...]
})
.catch((err) => {
  console.log(err);
});
```

I have 4 product so I have entered 4 product id to get sku details.

But I’m getting products length empty.

I have checked my products in the in app products in the play store it is active and product id is also same.

For buying the product

```
this.iap
.buy('prod1')
.then((data)=> {
   console.log(data);
})
.catch((err)=> {
   console.log(err);
});
```

After clicking on the product list which I am getting from my API. I have passed product id. After passing product id to buy the product I am getting following error:

[image]

I have uploaded the signed APK in the Beta in Play Store. Also added my email id under tester.

For Checking the in app purchase functionality I am signing the unsigned APK and the testing the functionality of in app purchase.

Can anyone provide the solution for the same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its working now.
We have to wait for google play atleast 12 hour after beta publish.